# Flutter – saving to an image file in PNG 8 format

Tags: android, flutter

PNG format images can be: 8 bits (index colors - up to 256 colors) and 24 bits (in RGB space - up to 256^3 colors).

For the same image of 1000x1000 pixels, I have two files of size - 8 bit (0.917 MBt) and 24 bit (2.33 MBt).

I need to record images with the smallest file size (with up to 256 colors and 100% quality). The smallest size gives the PNG 8-bit format (with GIF and JPG the file size is much larger).

In my Flutter code:

- Both PNG images (8 and 24 bit) load normally.
- The downloaded 24-bit image is recorded normally - the size of the save file is 2.31 MBt (this is normal).
- But when saving the loaded 8-bit image, I get a 2.05 MB file with the image in RGB space (not index colors).

What and how should I fix my Flutter code to record (save) my 8-bit PNG image so that the file size is ~1.0 MBt (in index colors)?

I couldn't find anything useful about my question on the Internet. Thanks in advance for any help or link, and especially thanks for the complete working code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:io';
    
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Load Image
  final ui.Image image = await loadImage("assets/images/image_8_bit.png");
  // Save image
  await saveImage(image, "assets/images/image_8_bit__save.png");
}
    
Future<ui.Image> loadImage(String imagePath) async {
  final ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
  final Uint8List imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(imageData);
  final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return frameInfo.image;
}

Future<void> saveImage(ui.Image image, String filename) async {
  final ByteData? byteData =
      await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

  await File(filename).writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
}
```

Comment: The indexed 8 bit colour PNG file should be a fair bit smaller than 1MB if the image is anything like a normal image. It will only be that size if the image is almost incompressible. The utility [PNGOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNGOUT) will let you compress a 24 bit PNG to indexed 8bit form which should give you an idea of the right size and allow you to test your read routine independently. My guess is there is a flag lurking somewhere you have to set to tell it to save as 8bit PNG.

Comment: 1. I wrote 0.917 Mbt.
2. The downloaded 8-bit image is absolutely normal and full-color (within 256 colors).
3. I understand/hope that there should be such a flag - that's what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found the necessary code flutter for saving an image in PNG 8 bit format (with an indexed color table - up to 256 colors) while maintaining 100% quality. Allows you to record an image 3.5 times smaller than a regular PNG 24 bit, significantly smaller compared to jpg and gif, and especially compared to bmp and tiff.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {

  // Load image
  var imageBytes = await File("assets/images/image.png").readAsBytes();

  img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);

  // Convert to 8 bit  
  img.Image resized = img.quantize(image!, numberOfColors: 256);

  // Save image
  final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();  
  List<int> png = img.encodePng(resized);  
  await File('${dir.path}/image_8_bit.png').writeAsBytes(png);  
}
```